# Node form validates fields with #access = FALSE after ajax image upload

Tags: 7, ajax

I have a node form for a content type rendered using *drupal_get_form()*, I wanted to hide some fields so I altered this form and set attribute *#access* to `FALSE` in order to hide it and not validate it.

Until this point everything goes nice but now I have a scenario that this form has an image field with ajax upload button, after removing / re-uploading the image the form validates the required fields that I already set its *#access* to `FALSE`.

I think that the form is rebuilt and all alteration to fields with `#access = FALSE` gone away. What should I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to hide the fields so that when the form is rebuilt (with AJAX or normal page load) the fields will still be hidden.

Also if you wanna make a field not validate then use the **code below** in your [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) hook.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'your_form_id'){
    // To hide the field
    $form['your_field']['#access'] = false;
    // To remove validation
    $form['your_field']['#required'] = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I already implemented HOOK_form_alter but I think all the alteration I did is discarded when the form is rebuild using the image field ajax.

Comment: @AmirIskander Did you add any condition like if(arg(0) == 'something') { //hide the fields } ? If so then it might not work because when the image gets uploaded, it calls an AJAX url and the url arguments will be different. It would be helpfull if you add your code.